# Html with questions and answers

Tags: treeview

I want to create a html page with a lot of questions and answers
The display for this html page must be like this:

**+** question one

**+** question two

**+** question three

clicking to **+** of the question one appears the answer one and so on

Can I also do this in wordpress content

Comment: Never used Wordpress but it sounds like you could do something like this using a [jQuery UI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/). That's assuming that you want the answers to be displayed on the same page under each question.

Comment: Thank you this is what I want! In wordpress I used it with 2 plugins (widgetize pages and phpcode).

Answer (score 0):

You can use bullet pointe in html.

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li>Your text</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

If you want to make a quiz you will need to use javascript though. Html is only for web design and stuff. You can’t do much with html alone.